# passing data from html form data to mysql database form fails express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I've been trying to send this information to the database, but it keeps on failing. I'm able to get the form data from the signup form since it shows whenever I attempt logging it in the console.

```
  const form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  var email = req.body.email;
  var lecturer_id = req.body.lecturer_id;
  var password = req.body.psw;
  var rpassword = req.body.pswrepeat;
  console.log(form);
  console.log(email);
  console.log(req.body);
  sql.query(
    `INSERT INTO registration
     (email, id, password, rpassword) 
     VALUES ("${req.body.email},${req.body.lecturer_id},${req.body.password},${req.body.rpassword}" );`,
    function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        res.redirect("signup");
      }
    }
  );
```

here's my form
I tried different format of the SQL queries and I'm still getting the same result. I also went through the express documentation

```
<form action="/signup" method="POST">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img
              src="104052-01.png"
              alt="logo"
              class="avatar"
              style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
            />
          </div>

          <!--<h1>Sign Up</h1>-->
          <p style="text-align: center">
            Please fill in this form to create an account.
          </p>
          <hr />

          <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required />
          <label for="lecturer_id"><b>ID</b></label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter ID"
            name="lecturer_id"
            required
          />

          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            name="psw"
            required
          />

          <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Repeat Password"
            name="pswrepeat"
            required
          />
          <p>
            Already have an account?
            <a href="login.html" style="color: dodgerblue">login</a>.
          </p>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: what error message you are getting?

Comment: That has nothing to with your form or express, but with the way you create your query. Use parameterized queries and not string templates or string concatenation. It will make your app more secure and less error prone. Your query is `VALUES("john@doe.com, mylecturrer, my password, my password")` which is obviously wrong

Comment: And if you already check for an error, you should also log it somewhere. It probably would have given you a hint about the invalid  query., ie something like "*Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*"